# Splitting a string after x number of new lines

Tags: .net, regex, string, split

I haven't managed to find a solution online to this in .net yet.

I need to be able to separate a string of about 42,000 lines into individual strings of 5,000 lines each.

String is of the form

```
"some stuff\d\nsome things\d\n..."
```

Repeating around 42,000 times. So realistically I need 9 strings, 8 will contain 5000 \d\n and one will contain 2000. But it needs to work in a general case.

So the string needs to be broken at every 5000th \d\n and saved as a separate string.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Show us enough of your input data to be able to know its format, and enough of your code to be able to know what you've attempted so far. Also, what do you mean by that isolated sentence "In response to a time out error"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort was shown

Comment: Edited, I hope that's less vague.

Comment: I did try the answer suggested which I couldn't get to work as the class I'm using is partial.
The String.Split() method didn't seem to extend functionality to include splitting strings after a certain amount of repeated characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit following clarification: once you have split your long strings on each `\d\n` then this generic extension method can be used to batch the strings up into batches of 5000 with any remaining in the final batch:

```
string[] longList = reallyLongString
                   .Split(new string[] { "\d\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var batchesOfStrings = longList.Batch(5000);

foreach (var batch in batchesOfStrings)
{
   … 
}
```

Extension  method (must be in a static class):

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    var batch = new List<T>(batchSize);

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        batch.Add(item);
        if (batch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return batch;
            batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }

    if (batch.Any())
    {
        yield return batch;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not convinced this is entirely what I'm looking for. I want to split a string after \d\n
Which perhaps means using some regex?

Comment: `string[] longList = reallyLongString.Split(new string[] { "\d\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: This will only split it into 42,000 strings, which doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: .. and then you call `var batches = longList.Batch(5000)`, as shown in the answer.

Comment: I see.
I managed to work around this shortcoming to fix my original problem, but I will try this approach to see if it answers the original question.